# Display element outside of its parent iframe and over another iframe

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I need to show some part of a div ( which is the element of an iframe) outside of its parent iFrame and also over another iFrame.

Like so:

```
+---------------------------------------------------+
|  Parent IFrame                                    |
|                                 +-------+         |
|                                 | DIV   |         |
+---------------------------------|       |---------+
+---------------------------------|       |---------+
|  2nd IFrame                     |       |         |
|                                 |       |         |
|                                 +-------+         |
+---------------------------------------------------+
```

So, is it possible?

Comment: Can you add what you have achieved with HTML and CSS

Comment: <head>
        <title>test</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
        <style type="text/css">
            iframe { width:500px; height:200px; }
   
   
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        
            <iframe id ="helTest" scrolling="no" src="index.html"></iframe>
        
        
            <iframe src="http://www.google.com"></iframe>
       
    </body>                                                                                                                          The div is coming from index.html

Comment: No, that is not possible. Each iframe is a separate window instance, and you can not display the content anywhere "outside" of it.